# How to properly use a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have two directories. Both of them contain TXT files. For every TXT file in `dir_1` I'm trying to get the matching TXT file in `dir_2`. There is a match if the date (in the file name) of `dir_1` matches with the date of files in `dir_2`.

```
dir_1 = c:\data\desktop\pointA\txt-files
dir_2 = c:\data\desktop\pointB\txt-files
```

`dir_1` contains files like this (these directory can contain multiple files of same date, but different time):

```
AAA_C1_20200907-07u43m55s_ab.txt
AAA_T8_20200907-08u18m55s_ab.txt
FFF_T8_20201025-12u58m55s_ab.txt
FFF_T8_20201025-05u53m55s_ab.txt
```

`dir_2` contains files like this (these files have a unique date):

```
MM2020-09-07-AB.dat
MM2020-10-25-AB.dat
MM2020-10-26-AB.dat
```

**This is my code:**

```
dir_1 = os.listdir(dir_1)
dir_2 = os.listdir(dir_2)

dir_2_dates = []
for file in dir_2:
    find = re.search("MM(.+?)AB", file).group(1)
    dir_2_dates.append(find)

for dir_1_file in dir_1:
    dir_1_date = re.search("_(.\d+)-", dir_1_date ).group(1)
    if dir_1_date in dir_2_dates:
            
            matching_dir_2 = [file for file in dir_2 if file == dir_1_date ]
            print(matching_dir_2)
```

**Desired output:**

```
MM20200907AB.dat
MM20200907AB.dat
MM20201025AB.dat
MM20201025AB.dat
```

**My current output is empty**

Comment: As a first debugging step, have you tried to print what the dates you extracted look like?

Comment: Seems like you are comparing strings like `20200907` to strings like `2020-09-07-`. Python does not know that those are supposed to be dates, and that they should be equal. You'll have to normalize them so they actually _are_ equal.

Comment: Can you guys show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues. Your first data match leaves the trailing slash. So this removes that. Next, you are matching with slashes to without, so this strips those. Last, I don't know why there is a comprehension in the last for  loop. Here is a working implementation, but I'm unsure if it is what you're after, since your desired output lists 4 files that don't even exist in either list.

```
import re

DIR1 = [
    "AAA_C1_20200907-07u43m55s_ab.txt",
    "AAA_T8_20200907-08u18m55s_ab.txt",
    "FFF_T8_20201025-12u58m55s_ab.txt",
    "FFF_T8_20201025-05u53m55s_ab.txt",
]

DIR2 = [
    "MM2020-09-07-AB.dat",
    "MM2020-10-25-AB.dat",
    "MM2020-10-26-AB.dat",
]

dir_2_dates = []
for file in DIR2:
    find = re.search("MM(.+?)-AB", file).group(1).replace("-", "")
    dir_2_dates.append(find)

print([x for x in DIR1 if re.search("_(.\d+)-", x).group(1) in dir_2_dates])
```

output:

```
[
    'AAA_C1_20200907-07u43m55s_ab.txt',
    'AAA_T8_20200907-08u18m55s_ab.txt',
    'FFF_T8_20201025-12u58m55s_ab.txt',
    'FFF_T8_20201025-05u53m55s_ab.txt'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest first grouping the filenames from `dir_2` in a dictionary, using the date as the key. This way, you do not have to search the entire `dir_2` again for each file from `dir_1`.
Then, you can just look up the files from `dir_2` in that dict for any date in a file from `dir_1`. Make sure to normalize the dates though, to have the same format, i.e. remove the `-` from the dates in `dir_2`:

```
import re, collections

by_date = collections.defaultdict(list)
for f in dir_2:
    d = re.search("MM(.+?)-AB", f).group(1).replace("-", "")
    by_date[d].append(f)

for f in dir_1:
    d = re.search("_(.\d+)-", f).group(1)
    if d in by_date:
        print(f, "->", by_date[d])
```

This does not use a list comprehension, but should be considerably faster.

Comment: This is great, mind if I ask you some additional things in chat? It has something to do with the directory https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237147/discussion-between-booboo-and-mediterraneo

Comment: @ManCity10 Did not see your comment; what is it, can't you post it here as a another comment?

Comment: Well it needs much explanation, cant do it in a comment.. after the `if d in by_date` I want to open the txt files in dir_2 that are matched with the current file in dir_1. So I want to load some data from that files in dir_2 based on some requierments and write it back to the by_data[d]. But I need this to be done for every key in by_data actually

Comment: @ManCity10 It might be better to post this as a separate follow-up question (you can link to this question for context), explaining what exactly "some data" and "some requirements" are, and how to write those back to the dict (which wasn't even part of your original setup).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
[file for file in dir_2 if file == dir_1_date ]
```

where file is name of file in dir2, i.e.:

```
MM2020-09-07-AB.dat
MM2020-10-25-AB.dat
MM2020-10-26-AB.dat
```

and compare (`==`) it to `dir_1_date` which is

```
dir_1_date = re.search("_(.\d+)-", dir_1_date ).group(1)
```

therefore `dir_1_date` is any character followed by one or more digits. There is no possibility for equalness as mentioned filenames consist of letters, digits, `-` and `.`

Comment: so what should I do to get my desired output?